# Lumen : maatwebsite/excel is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, maatwebsite-excel

Hello I am using maatwebsite/excel : version 3.0 to save files as **.xls** .

I have added it to my composer.json then ran `composer update`.

In my bootstrap/app.php I added:

```
$app->register(Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class);
```

In my controller I used the following code:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
Excel::create('Laravel Excel', function($excel)use($data) {

$excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet)use ($data) {
                $sheet->rows($data);
});
})->store('xls')->download('xls');
```

`$data` is an array shown below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [srNum] => 1
            [user_name] => test user2
            [loggedin_at] => 2018-05-14 14:06:48
            [username] => tezzxzser2                
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [srNum] => 2
            [user_name] => test user2
            [loggedin_at] => 2018-05-14 14:18:39
            [username] => tezzxzser2

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [srNum] => 3
            [user_name] => test user2
            [loggedin_at] => 2018-05-15 07:05:14
            [username] => tezzxzser2

        )
}
```

It is not working and gives me the following error:

> Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory] is not
>   instantiable.

Also, where does it store the excel file when saved?

Comment: $data need to be a multilevel array instead you return an array of objects. my guess it will save in storage/xls. You should give the path as the second argument in store ->store('xls',
            storage_path('app/public/reports/')). It's in the docs

Comment: can you give me example for which type of array I can pass in this,bcz it is now store excel but it is empty not write any thing it

Comment: thanks for your help for give path store excel, my excel is now exported ,I have used 2.1.0 version ,dont know what is issue with 3.0 version ,2.1.0 is working